# Hot to add buttons (links) to Geonode Menu bar using geonode-project 4.1.x?

Tags: django, geonode

I just install Geonode-project 4.1.x and try to follow the official documentation (https://docs.geonode.org/en/4.x/devel/workshops/index.html#customize-the-look-and-feel) to customize the look and add some Links (buttons) to the navigarion bar.
So far I have created the templatetags folder and create the "get_menu_json.py" file with the following content
[image: Folde structure]

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_base_right_topbar_menu(context):

    #is_mobile = _is_mobile_device(context)

    #if is_mobile:
    #    return []

    return [
        {
            "type": "link",
            "href": "/",
            "label": "Custom 3"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "href": "/",
            "label": "Custom 4"
        },
    ]
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_base_left_topbar_menu(context):

    #is_mobile = _is_mobile_device(context)

    return [
        {
            "type": "link",
            "href": "/",
            "label": "Custom 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "href": "/",
            "label": "Custom 2"
        },
    ]
```

I have also modified the settings.py to add the templatetags

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['libraries']={
                'my_template_tag_menu': 'templatetags.get_menu_json',
            }
```

But this is not working. Geonode is still showing the same buttons (Dataset, Maps, etc). My intention is to add (I am saying add, not override) buttons to the Navigation Bar, so i can access the new views I have created for geonode project. I am using geonode-project 4.1.x. Documentations appears to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not relevant for you any longer, but I solved this in the following way:

First, you want to add the "templatetags"-folder in the subfolder containing your app, so in your case, the "geocollection" folder. Django will only detect tag libraries if they are in this folder.
In the folder, create a Python file with a different name, e.g., "custom_tags.py":

```
from django import template
from geonode_mapstore_client.templatetags import get_menu_json

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_base_right_topbar_menu(context):
    tags = get_menu_json.get_base_right_topbar_menu(context)
    tags += [
       {
           "type": "link",
           "href": "/",
           "label": "Custom 3"
       },
       {
           "type": "link",
           "href": "/",
           "label": "Custom 4"
       },
   ]
   return tags


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_base_left_topbar_menu(context):
    tags = get_menu_json.get_base_left_topbar_menu(context)

    tags += [
        {
           "type": "link",
           "href": "/",
           "label": "Custom 1"
        },
        {
           "type": "link",
           "href": "/",
           "label": "Custom 2"
        },
    ]
    return tags
```

This will combine any new tags you add with existing tags already stored in the geonode_mapstore_client library.

Lastly, you need to adjust the menu bar to reference the new tag library over the old one. To do this, copy the file [topbar.html](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-mapstore-client/blob/master/geonode_mapstore_client/templates/geonode-mapstore-client/snippets/topbar.html) from the geonode_mapstore_client into your template/geonode-mapstore-client/snippets folder and add the line `{% load custom_tags %}` under `{% load get_menu_json %}`.